# Find files by change date

Tags: files, find, timestamps, file-search

I'd like to search recursively for files with a specific Change date. Note, this is not the Access or Modify date, but the Change date as outputted by `stat`.

```
#stat prototype.js
  File: `prototype.js'
  Size: 175637      Blocks: 352        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 803h/2051d  Inode: 18146171    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  507/user)   Gid: (  505/user)
Access: 2016-11-03 04:54:05.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2016-01-06 03:38:54.000000000 -0600
Change: 2016-07-23 03:42:37.000000000 -0500
```

In my specific case, I'd like to find all files with a Change date of 2016-07-23. The OS is CentOS release 6.4. Thanks!

Comment: "Note, this is not the Access or Modify date, but the change date as outputted by stat"

Comment: CentOS should use GNU `find` - which has `-ctime`, `-newerct` etc., no?

Comment: @steeldriver That looks like the nugget of information I needed! Will report back...

Comment: @Gilles As mentioned in the question, I was interested in finding files by Change date. The "duplicate" question you have linked to finds files by Modified date. This is actually different criteria, with subtly different answers so I wouldn't class this as a dupe :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command that sufficed was:

```
find . -type f -newerct 2016-07-23 ! -newerct 2016-07-24
```